# Integrating $\sqrt{4-x^2}\,dx$?

Tags: calculus, integration

Assume we evaluate $\int \sqrt{4-x^2}\,dx $ by using the substitution $x=2 \sin(t)$ from which it follows that $4-x^2 = 4\cos^2 (t) $ so that $\int \sqrt{4-x^2}\,dx  =4\int \sqrt{\cos^2 (t)} \cos(t)\,dt  $.

In order to get  $\int \sqrt{4-x^2}\,dx = 2\arcsin(x/2)+\frac{x\sqrt{4-x^2}}{2}+C$, we need to write $\sqrt{\cos^2 (t)} = \cos(t)$ .

My question is -

> what are the arguments that allows us to assume that $\cos(t)\geq 0 $
>   so that $\sqrt{\cos^2 (t)} = \cos(t)$?

(taking $\sqrt{\cos^2 (t)} = -\cos(t)$ for example yields a wrong result)

Comment: $\sqrt{x}$ always means the positive square root of $x$ by convention. This has been mentioned in many previous questions, such as [this one](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/547792/square-root-of-x2).

Comment: @TobyMak that's not the point of the question, I think. He knows that $\sqrt{\cos^2 x}$ = $\lvert \cos x \rvert$, but if $\cos x < 0$, that's $-\cos x$ (which makes the integration go wrong)

Comment: Because the sine function produces all of its values on the interval $[-\frac \pi 2,\frac \pi 2]$, you may assume $t\in [-\frac \pi 2,\frac \pi 2]$. This ensures that $\cos t\geq 0$.

Comment: By the way, you can also integrate this by parts without a trig. substitution.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The range of definition of the integrand is $-2\leq x\leq2$, so $-1\leq\sin t\leq1$. Therefore $-\frac{\pi}{2}\leq t\leq\frac{\pi}{2}$ (replacement must be monotonic) and $\cos t\geq0$.

Comment: Got it. Thanks!

Comment: @Dr.John, I’ll add that this is also related to the range of the arcsine function when doing the reverse change.

Comment: Dear @thing - many thanks! I absolutely agree. The problem is that in contrast to the multivariable case, teachers often forget to mention that the replacement should be injective also in the single variable case. The $arcsin$ argument indeed provides an interesting further insight. Thanks!