# I found $\lim _{x\to \:0}\left(1-\frac{1}{x}\left(\sqrt{1+x^2}-1\right)\right)$ to be -infinity

Tags: calculus, limits, functions, roots, infinity

Here is what I tried to calculate:

$\lim _{x\to \:0}\left(1-\frac{1}{x}\left(\sqrt{1+x^2}-1\right)\right)$

When I calculated for 0-(I mean negative zero) I found it to be -infinity but the solution found it to be 1

Can anyone verify it for me please?

My solution:

I found the equation as it is to have an intermediate form(1 - 0/0) so I tried to remove that by simplifying it to

$1 - \sqrt{\frac{1}{x^2} + 1} + \frac{1}{x}$

So I calculated limit to 0-(Negative zero) and I found it to be -infinity

Comment: @AlbusDumbledore Okay. Wait a minute, I will edit the question.

Comment: @AlbusDumbledore I added a part of my solution now.

Answer (score 2):

Your method is incorrect as it is of the $-\infty+\infty$ form and nothing can be said about it.Also $\frac{\sqrt{1+x^2}}{x}=\sqrt{1+\frac{1}{x^2}}$ need not be true (what happens when $x$ is negative?)

---

let $x=\tan t$ we have to calculate $$\lim_{t\to 0}1-\frac{\sqrt{1+\tan^2t}-1}{\tan t}=\lim_{t \to 0}(1-\tan (t/2))=1$$

Comment: Why is it incorrect?

Comment: @TechnoKnight  $-\infty+\infty$ can take any value ,in fact $\infty$ is more of a symbol,

Comment: I don't get it. What −∞+∞ has anything to do here?

Comment: @TechnoKnight $\frac{\sqrt{1+x^2}}{x}=\sqrt{1+\frac{1}{x^2}}$ need not be true

Comment: Why is it not true?

Comment: Take $x=-1$ and see are they equal?

Comment: @TechnoKnight put $x=-1$ LHS is negative and RHS is postive ,,in general $x=\sqrt{x^2}$ need not be true rather $|x|=\sqrt{x^2}$

Comment: @Vilakshan its a coincidence that we used the same counter examples and posted in same time(lol)

Comment: @AlbusDumbledore Yeah, lol even I was about to write the same sentence that you just wrote. :)

Comment: Oooh. I got it now. It's supposed to be the absolute value of x not just x

Comment: @TechnoKnight of course,anyway  valid doubt for a few moments i also pondred on your method

Comment: @Vilakshan Thank you both, I always make mistakes when I do limits, I hate the hell out of them haha. Thanks again!

Answer (score 1):

Imho easiest way:
$$\frac{1}{x}\left(\sqrt{1+x^2}-1\right)=\frac{x}{\sqrt{1+x^2}+1}\to0$$

Now about your solution: you have little mistake, it should be
$$\frac{1}{x}\left(\sqrt{1+x^2}-1\right)=\text{sign(x)}\sqrt{1+\frac{1}{x^2}}-\frac{1}{x}$$
so you obtain not $-\infty$ but $\infty-\infty$ which is undefined.

Comment: I calculated by using your form and I still found it to be -infinity

Comment: Where you found infinity? simply put $x=0$ in last fraction in my answer.

Comment: I'm calculating for negative zero

Comment: No difference in this case. Where and which problem do you see in my solution?

Comment: Why can't we do like I did in my solution? I'm really sorry about all these questions, I just have a big problem in limits and I never quite understood them.

Comment: I added my consideration of mistake in your solution. Feel free to ask more if/when need.

Comment: There should be no sign(x) because $x^2$ got out of the square root which means it becomes x and x/x = 1

Comment: It's your mistake: by default square root is defined to be the principal square root  $\sqrt{x^2}=|x|=x\text{sign(x)}$ look here https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/547792/square-root-of-x2   or here https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Square_root

Comment: @skutch Oh yeah I got it now. It was my mistake. I always mix them up haha. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Using the standard [limit properties](https://tutorial.math.lamar.edu/classes/calci/limitsproperties.aspx):
$$\begin{align} 
\lim_{x\to 0} (1 - \frac{1}{x}(\sqrt{x^2+1}-1)) &= \lim_{x\to 0}1 - \lim_{x\to 0} \frac{\sqrt{x^2+1} - 1}{x} \\ 
&= 1 - \lim_{x\to 0}\left( \frac{\sqrt{x^2+1} - 1}{x}\cdot \frac{\sqrt{x^2+1}+1}{\sqrt{x^2+1}+1}\right) \\ 
&= 1 - \lim_{x\to 0}\frac{x^2+1-1}{x(\sqrt{x^2+1}+1)} \\ &= 1 - \lim_{x\to 0}\frac{x}{\sqrt{x^2+1}+1} \\ &= 1 - \frac{\lim_{x\to 0}x}{\lim_{x\to 0}(\sqrt{x^2+1}+1)} \\ &= 1 - \frac{0}{\sqrt{0^2+1}+1} = 1 - 0 = 1 \end{align}$$

**$\underline{\text{EDIT}}$**: In response to a question in the comments, here's how to find the limit of the same function at infinity: $$\begin{align}
\lim_{x\to \infty}\left( 1-\frac{1}{x}(\sqrt{x^2+1}-1)\right) & = \lim_{x\to\infty}1 - \lim_{x\to\infty}\left( \frac{\sqrt{x^2+1}}{x}-\frac{1}{x}\right) \\ &= 1 - \left( \lim_{x\to\infty}\frac{\sqrt{x^2+1}}{x} - \lim_{x\to\infty}\frac{1}{x} \right) \\ &= 1 - \left( \lim_{x\to\infty} \frac{\sqrt{x^2+1}}{x}-0 \right) \\ &= 1 - \lim_{x\to\infty} \frac{\sqrt{x^2\left( 1+\frac{1}{x^2}\right) }}{x} \\ &= 1 - \lim_{x\to\infty} \frac{x\sqrt{1+\frac{1}{x^2}}}{x} \\ &= 1 - \lim_{x\to\infty} \sqrt{1+\frac{1}{x^2}} = 1-1=0
\end{align}$$

Comment: Thank you, can I ask you one more question? How do I calculate for infinity? I kept trying but I didn't find it

Comment: @TechnoKnight this particular limit or in general?

Comment: This particular limit, I mean.

Comment: @TechnoKnight I updated my answer to show the computation. I tried to demonstrate each step explicitly because the techniques used here generalise to other limits easily.

Comment: But I don't get it. Isn't it supposed to be |x| instead of just x when you got it out of the square root?

Comment: @TechnoKnight not in this case, because we're evaluating the limit at infinity. By definition, this means we're only considering positive values of $x$. See Definition 6 [here](https://tutorial.math.lamar.edu/classes/calcI/defnoflimit.aspx) if you need a refresher as to what it is.

Comment: So why didn't we do that when the limit was for 0, negative zero and positive zero then? When we do limit for negative zero, it becomes $-x$ and when we do for positive zero it becomes $x$ why we can't do that?

Comment: @TechnoKnight but we can! That's essentially what zkutch's answer is about. $\sqrt{x^2} = \lvert x \rvert$ for all $x$. But since we had $x$ in the denominator, whether it's positive or negative determines the sign of the entire fraction.